# Use the `emconfigure`, `emmake` command to compile it to a `.wasm` file

Tags: c++, configure, emcc, emmake, emconfigure

I am trying to build a `cpp` project into a `wasm` file using the command like this `./emcc test/hello_world.c -o hello.html` from the link here. That works.

However, when I am using a c++ project that has `.configure` file and the result creates multiple `.exe` files - `php.exe` and `php-cli.exe`. How do I use the `emconfigure`, `emmake` command to compile it to a `.wasm` file. Any reference?

I was trying to build `php` project available after make into a `php.wasm` file.

https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html

https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html